# Laravel Botman gives a 404 error in the developer console

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I have moved a development from a local wamp server to our production environment, I have fixed style issues etc but having a problem when trying to initiate a conversation. Network info in the developer console gives a 404 not found error - https://*myURL*/botman . Is there a way to modify this in a config file to point to the correct location?

I have tried changing the .env file and adding the URL to APP_URL but didn't work.

Comment: post more information, e.g. .env file and route

Comment: To be honest this is all pretty new to me, the only thing that made sense to change was the APP_URL fro localhost to the site  APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MyKey
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=MyURL

Comment: what is myurl? e.g. 127.0.0.1? 192.168.0.103? and what is routes.php?